# URL with query string validation using PHP

Tags: php, url, query-string, url-validation

I need a PHP validation function for URL with Query string (parameters seperated with &). currently I've the following function for validating URLs

```
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/';

echo preg_match($pattern, $url);
```

This function correctly validates input like

`google.com`
`www.google.com`
`http://google.com`
`http://www.google.com` ...etc

But this won't validate the URL when it comes with parameters (Query string). for eg.

```
http://google.com/index.html?prod=gmail&act=inbox
```

I need a function that accepts both types of URL inputs. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [**filter_var**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if(filter_var($yoururl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
  echo 'Ok';
}
```

might do the trick, although there are problems with url not preceding the schema:
http://codepad.org/1HAdufMG

You can turn around the issue by placing an `http://` in front of urls without it.
As suggested by @DaveRandom, you could do something like:

```
$parsed = parse_url($url); 
if (!isset($parsed['scheme'])) $url = "http://$url";
```

before feeding the filter_var() function.

Overall it's still a simpler solution than some extra-complicated regex, though..

It also has these flags available:

> FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED FILTER_VALIDATE_URL  Requires the URL to
>   contain a path part. FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED   FILTER_VALIDATE_URL 
>   Requires the URL to contain a query string.

Comment: FTR, I think the most sensible approach to making sure the scheme is present would be `$parsed = parse_url($str); if (!isset($parsed['scheme'])) $url = "http://$url";`

Comment: I Used Parse_url for checking whether query exists in URI. Almost Worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Some might think this is not a 100% bullet-proof,
but you can give a try as a start

Comment: Although `This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts.`

Comment: @DamienPirsy Indeed, I was going to answer with exactly this, until I started playing with it and discovered that I couldn't actually come up with anything that would make it return false. Even passing `"\x00"` or `"this@is.not.a.url"` doesn't break it...